# Calculating maximum using existence in pipe separated column values in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

COnsider below  table

Emp Table
Employee can belong to more than one department in below form

```
emp departments
E1   D1|D2|D3
E2   D2
E3   D1|D3
```

Departments Table

```
departments    Manager
D1              M1
D2              M2
```

How can we find the manager with the maximum employees?

Comment: You are storing the data in **Wrong** way. Have individual rows for each `employee,department` combination

Comment: See normalisation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, if you can, you should change the structure of your data.
The employees table should contain one emp-department relation on each row, employee with more than one should have several rows.

If you stick to the current structure, you can use `join` to get a table with the mappings between manager's and employees:

```
select D.manager, E.emp from departments as D inner join employees as E on
 E.departments like CONCAT( '%|' , D.department, '|%');
```

and on this table you can use count to get the number of employees per manager:

```
select manager, count(*) from (
  select D.manager, E.emp from departments as D inner join employees as E on
    E.departments like CONCAT( '%|' , D.department, '|%')
) as X group by X.emp;
```

Comment: Well, I like the first paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

As others have actually suggested your data structure needs normalizing. If you had a junction table in between employees and departments they belong to you wouldn't probably even need to ask this question as it would be trivial.

However, if you're stuck with what you have for now here's a workaround solution using [`FIND_IN_SET()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function and `LEFT JOIN` on expression where we change `|` to `,` with `REPLACE()` for proper delimiter to the join condition function argument:

```
select d.manager, count(*) AS employees_cnt
from departments d
left join employees e on find_in_set(d.departments, replace(e.departments,'|',',')) > 0
group by d.manager
order by employees_cnt desc
```

Result:

```
manager     employees_cnt
M1          2
M2          2
```

If you only need one, then you can add `LIMIT 1` clause at the end of the query, but bear in mind that ties would be resolved by order by clause.